# Fetch NSarray from the NSDictionary of NSArray using objectForKey

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, nsarray, nsdictionary

I have a `NSArray` which contain n number of `NSDictionary` sampleArray =

```
 (
            {
            0 = 0;
            1 = 0;
        },
            {
            0 = 86400;
            1 = 2;
        },
            {
            0 = 172800;
            1 = 4;
        },
            {
            0 = 259200;
            1 = 5;
        }

    )
```

Now I need to fetch the NSArray for `objectForKey` 0 `[sampleArray objectForKey:[NSNumber numberWithInt:0]]`, my result NSArray should be like 
(0,86400,172800,259200) but I am unable to fetch the result and the app crashes.

Normally for NSDictionary, if key value is set using `NSString` `valueForKey` the above operation is performed successfully but if key value is set using an object like NSNumber `objectForKey` I am unable to perform the operation.

Please help me to get a solution, any suggestion would be appreciated!!

Comment: `objectForKey:` is a method on `NSDictionary`, not `NSArray`

Comment: Yes, I checked it. Is there any solution to fetch my above sample result ??

Comment: key is always is a string.. but that does not mean if you replace it with string it will work in your case..

Comment: @PrashanthRajagopalan yes, all answers do that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A very straight forward way if your keys are `NSNumber` objects:

```
NSMutableArray *result = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (NSDictionary *d in a) {
    if (d[@0]) {
        [result addObject:d[@0]];
    }
}
```

Comment: @Sebastin Thanks for all your replies!! I guess this is the apt solution for my question. The thing is I wonder why the NSArray has property for 'valueForKey' and why not for 'objectForKey'!!

Comment: As the docs say "`valueForKey:` Returns an array containing the results of invoking `valueForKey:` using key on each of the array's objects." It only works for strings though.

Comment: @Sebastian didnt know that ... although I usually have string keys anyways.

Answer (score 3):

THIS doesnt work - im sorry: I didnt see you didnt have Strings as keys + I didnt know KVC only works with strings

I leave it though

---

what you are looking for is

```
NSArray *zeros = [mainArray valueForKey:@"0"];
```

it gets "0" from each dict in array

Comment: No, it is not working!! I am getting the result as "<null>",
    "<null>",
    "<null>" .

Comment: Are your keys `NSString` or `NSNumber` objects?

Comment: NSNumber.. Please check my sampleArray if it is NSSting it should be @"0", but I had mentioned as 0

Comment: Should it? `- (id)valueForKey:(NSString *)key`

Comment: @PrashanthRajagopalan: You are right (and my previous comment is wrong). KVC works only with string keys.

Comment: sorry Ill edit it. didn't see the keys weren't strings.. kinda a typical IMHO... except for a cache

Answer (score 0):

What you have do is

```
  NSMutableArray *arrResult = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
 for(int i=0;i<[sampleArray count];i++)
  {
    NSString *strValue = [[sampleArray objectAtIndex:i] valueforkey:@"0"];

   [ arrResult addobject:strValue];
 }
```

let me know it is working or not!!!!

Happy coding!!!!!

Comment: Key Value Coding.. cool stuff: http://www.itsaboutcode.com/blog/2011/11/30/what-is-key-value-coding-kvc-and-why-we-need-it/

Answer (score 0):

here you can try  NSArray *tempArray

```
for (NSDictionary *list in tempArray)
{
    [firstArray addObject:[list objectForKey:@"0"];
    [secondArray addObject:[list objectForKey:@"1"];
}
```